# TTaskBar: Setting ProgressState to "Indeterminate" does not work as expected

Tags: windows, delphi, vcl

I use the TTaskbar component in my Delphi application to show the progress of the current operation in the TaskBar.

At the beginning it should show a "Indeterminate" progress (known as pbsMarquee in the context of a ProgressBar).

If I set the status the "indeterminate" animation is only display a single time. I expect it to animate all the time until I change the ProgressState:

```
tbTaskBar.ProgressState := TTaskBarProgressState.Indeterminate;
```

Any thing I am missing? What I need to do to dislay the animation all the time?

Comment: I don't see this behavior. Can  you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I've never trusted `TTaskBar`, too many bugs over the years. I prefer to use the Win32 `ITaskBarList...` interfaces directly.